# is Dword still a word or is it two word

Tags: assembly, integer

I'm new to assembly language

can number -123,456 can be stored in one word?

-123, 456 is in range for a Dword but I'm confuse if a Dword is stil a word or is it two words
because Dword is use for 32 bits word

Comment: You didn't say which assembly language you are using. Different processors have different meanings for the term "dword".

Comment: As others have said, it means whatever the processor and language architects say it means.  In some cases a dword and word are the same size, in other cases not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a word is architecture specific. They usually refer to a unit that the ISA handles natively. In case of a Doubleword or DWORD, it's merely a unit which its size is twice the size of a word.

So if you are talking about an architecture where the size of a word is 16bit (e.g. Intel 8086), then  DWORDs can hold 32bits of information. Since -123456 is FFFE1DC0 (w/ sign extension to 32bit), it can indeed be stored in one DWORD.

Comment: thank you, I'm just a bit confuse if Dword is still a word since it read double word

Comment: @user1763658 They usually refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with the word "word" is that it is very ambiguous.  It used to mean "native word size" of a computer.  Which was all over the place in the early years.  Weird sizes too, multiples of 6 were popular, like 18 and 36 bits.  Back then everybody understood that "word" didn't say anything about the number of bits.  The term "byte" didn't get a meaning until much later.

That changed when micro-processors came around, first in 8 and 16-bit flavors.  Where "word" got to be synonymous with "16-bits".  That lasted a long time, until 32-bit processors became common.  Processors like the 386 whose native word size is 32-bits but could still address 16-bit quantities as well.  So to avoid breaking tons of assumptions, and keeping at least some of the existing assembly code compatible, they had to come up with a new word for the quantity of 32-bits.  That became "dword", double word or 2 x 16-bits.  And "word" stayed 16-bits, even though it now has nothing to do anymore with the native word size.